# The text of the uitableviewcell comes under section view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I faced with such a problem. Text my cell crawls under the table section, became a google but could not find a solution. Before doing these things, when I was only UITableViewController without additional elements such as segments. Everything worked perfectly. Tell me how to solve this problem. Thank you!

[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("CommonSectionTableView") as! CommonSectionTableView
        cell.titleLabel.text = self.ordersSectionName[section]
        return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 55.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code....

```
  //If you want to place a header
  let header = "Your Header Name"
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return header 
}

//If you using section header
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
return "Section \(Your Section Name or Array)"
}
```

Above code will put the headerView just above your tableView...

If you want to customise your headerView checkout the following questions

[How can we add image in UITableView section header using swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600375/how-can-we-add-image-in-uitableview-section-header-using-swift)
[Customize UITableView header section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611374/customize-uitableview-header-section)
http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-header-footer-table-view-ios8-swift

Comment: Can you upload another screenshot that covers the entire screen.did you look at the link.what output you getting same or any changes?